# What does *& mean in a function parameter

Tags: c++, function, parameters

If I have a function that takes `int *&`, what does it means?  How can I pass just an int or a pointer int to that function?

```
function(int *& mynumber);
```

Whenever I try to pass a pointer to that function it says:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'function(int *)'
note: candidate is 'function(int *&)'
```

Comment: That error is because of exactly what I was talking about with "it must be an l-value, not just an r-value". The rule in question is "you can't bind a temporary to a non-const reference", the result of the & "address of" operator is a temporary.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's a reference to a pointer to an int. This means the function in question can modify the pointer as well as the int itself.

You can just pass a pointer in, the one complication being that the pointer needs to be an l-value, not just an r-value, so for example

```
int myint;
function(&myint);
```

alone isn't sufficient and neither would 0/NULL be allowable, Where as:

```
int myint;
int *myintptr = &myint;
function(myintptr);
```

would be acceptable. When the function returns it's quite possible that `myintptr` would no longer point to what it was initially pointing to.

```
int *myintptr = NULL;
function(myintptr);
```

might also make sense if the function was expecting to allocate the memory when given a NULL pointer. Check the documentation provided with the function (or read the source!) to see how the pointer is expected to be used.

Answer (score 10):

Simply: a reference to a pointer.

In C, without references, the traditional way to "relocate" a pointer, is to pass a pointer to a pointer:

```
void c_find(int** p, int val); /* *p will point to the node with value 'val' */
```

In C++, this can be expressed by the reference syntax, to avoid the awkward double dereference.

```
void cpp_find(int*& p, int val); // p will point to the node with value 'val'
```

Answer (score 9):

It means a reference to a pointer to an int.  In other words, the function can change the parameter to point to something else.

To pass a variable in, just pass an int*.  As awoodland points out, what's passed in must be an [l-value](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/topic/com.ibm.vacpp6m.doc/language/ref/clrc05lvalue.htm).

**Edit:**

To build on awoodland's example:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int*& var)
{
    delete var;
    var = new int;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int* var = NULL;

    std::cout << var << std::endl;

    foo(var);   // this function can/will change the value of the pointer

    std::cout << var << std::endl;

    delete var;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, Good reference for l-value, I couldn't find anything worth linking to.

Comment: @awoodland, thank you.  I admit this was the first google hit for me.  I was looking for something more definitive, but didn't find a better reference.

Comment: If I understand well, if I have a function returning a pointer, I need to assign it to another pointer before passing it to the function?

Comment: @Apoc, I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Apoc, if the function just returns int* it can't be bound to a non-const reference to int*. It can be saved to a suitable variable and that variable can be bound to a reference later though.

Answer (score 2):

`function` takes a single parameter, `mynumber` which is a reference to a pointer to an `int`.

This is useful when you need  to pass a pointer to a function, and that function might *change* the pointer.  For example, if you function is implemented like this:

```
function(int*& mynumber)
{
  if( !mynumber )
    mynumber = new int;
  *mynumber = 42;
}
```

...Then something like this might happen in the calling code:

```
int main()
{
  int* mynumber = 0;
  function(mynumber); // function will change what "mynumber" points to
  cout << *mynumber;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a reference to a pointer to `int` - you would have to pass in the address of an `int` to this function, and be aware that the function could change the pointer through the reference.

Dumb example:

```
void func(int*& iref) 
{
    iref = new int;
}

int main()
{
    int i(0);
    int* pi(&i);

    func(pi);
    // pi no longer equal to &i

    return 0;
}
```